# Disable Copy/paste option in react native

Tags: android, react-native, clipboard, textinput

I want to disable clipboard(copy/paste) in my react-native app

contextMenuHidden={true} didn't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

Attaching below snippet that worked for me

> removeClippedSubviews={true}
> contextMenuHidden={true}
> onFocus={() => Clipboard.setString('')}
> onSelectionChange={() => Clipboard.setString('')}

```
<View removeClippedSubviews={true}>
                            <TextInput
                              contextMenuHidden={true}
                                onFocus={() => Clipboard.setString('')} 
                                onSelectionChange={() => Clipboard.setString('')}
                                style={styles.searchInput}
                                onChangeText={this.handleSearch}
                                value={search} />
                              </View>
```

Answer (score 1):

Clipboard use mostly in `TextInput` fields. you can refer to this post for disabling the clipboard for `TextInput` 
[Disable clipboard for TextInput in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54646327/disable-clipboard-for-textinput-in-react-native)

Comment: onFocus={() => Clipboard.setString('')} onSelectionChange={() => Clipboard.setString('')}. This snippet working incase of copy, also want to disable paste option

Comment: try this: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58521318/8116260)